# exclusive or (xor) operator?

Tags: xor, jq

Does jq have an exclusive or (AKA xor) operator?  I'm having trouble finding it in its documentation.

(I've had trouble finding other topics in the docs that I later found worked in jq and are documented. I probably didn't find them at first because I'd used poor search terms.)

I wanted jq to return all top-level objects from the input that have array properties containing one of two specific values, but not both values.

For example, given the input:

```
[
  {"letters": ["a", "c"]},
  {"letters": ["a", "b", "c"]},
  {"letters": ["b", "c"]}
]
```

I want only the objects whose `"letters"` property contains either `"a"` or `"b"`, but not both.

I ended up using the long-winded filter:

```
map(select(.letters//[]|((contains(["a"]) or contains(["b"])) and (contains(["a", "b"])|not))))
```

Which gave the correct output:

```
[{"letters":["a","c"]},{"letters":["b","c"]}]
```

But that's long, tedious, and a maintenance headache.  Is there a simpler way to do accomplish this?

A "jq play" snippet for this code: https://jqplay.org/s/mwBhsYud2F

PS: Even if there isn't any better solution than the one I've found, I'll be happy to receive constructive criticism about improving it.

Answer (score 1):

`xor` can easily be defined:

```
def xor($a;$b): ($a or $b) and (($a and $b)|not);
```

`contains` is tricky (it is probably better not to use it unless you have studied its subtleties). In general, it would be better to use `index`:

```
.letters | select( xor( index("a"); index("b") ))
```

For efficiency, it would be even better to use `IN` if your jq has it:

```
.letters as $a | select( xor( "a" | IN($a[]); "b" | IN($a[]) ))
```

Comment: This can be simplified a little since if $a and $b are truth values, $a xor $b is the same as $a != $b.

Comment: But `index` is not boolean.  And the jq boolean-valued operators do not require the arguments to be boolean.

Comment: Yes I realized that when testing your solution and settled on `def xor($a;$b): ($a|not) != ($b|not) ;`  One thing I stumbled across was that `def xor($a;$b): (a|not) != (b|not) ;` also worked (note missing $ within body).  It seems you can use `x` or `$x` within `def foo($x):` ... ;

Comment: Can you elaborate wrt `in()`?  `contains()` seems to be the right test for this, and I can understand possibly using `index()>=0`, but it seems like extra work would be required to use `in()`.

Comment: @LS recent jq supports [SQL-Style Operators](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) including `IN` (note upper-case). If it's not in your jq you can manually copy [its definition](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L307-L308).

Comment: I see! It's the function described in https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators.  Thanks for adding the example, too.  It seems much more awkward than `contains()` or `index()`, though.  Has it actually been proven to be more efficient?

Comment: Yes. The current implementation of index/1 is hopelessly (and needlessly) inefficient, but it is written in C so it is fast :-)

Comment: Yes, I see the `def` of index/1 now. It would appear to be slower than contains/1.  And in/1 is backwards (inverse?) to the comparison I want to make, so I'll probably stick with contains/1.

Comment: Are you aware that  '["ab", "cd"] | contains(["a"])'
yields true?

Comment: @jq170727 - "def($a)" is essentially short for "def(a): a as $a |".  Try this: def x($a;$b): 0 | $a + $b;
def y($a;$b): 0 | a + b;
1 | (x(.;.), y(.;.))

Comment: Ah that explains it!

Answer (score 0):

How about this: if `data.json` contains your sample data the command

```
$ jq -Mc '
  def xor($a;$b): $a != $b ;
  map(select(.letters|xor(contains(["a"]);contains(["b"]))))
' data.json
```

produces

```
[{"letters":["a","c"]},{"letters":["b","c"]}]
```

Note that the `xor` used above works here but isn't safe to use with non-boolean parameters.  A more robust version is:

```
def xor($a;$b): ($a|not) != ($b|not) ;
```

Comment: This answer is better than your earlier one.  Why didn't you just edit your earlier answer to add this solution, or even replace it entirely?  Between the answer by @peak and this one, you both are making it difficult to decide which should be the "accepted" answer.

Comment: You should select whichever you found most helpful. Overall I think [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309298/8379597) is better.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no duplicates in `.letters`, here is another way which takes advantage of a little-known use of array indexing:

```
$ jq -Mc 'map(select(.letters|.[["a"]]+.[["b"]]|length==1))' data.json
```

produces

```
[{"letters":["a","c"]},{"letters":["b","c"]}]
```

This works because if `$x` is an array `$x[ ["a"] ]` returns the indices of `"a"` within `$x`. e.g.

```
$ jq -Mnc '["a","c"][["a"]]'
[0]
$ jq -Mnc '["a","c"][["b"]]'
[]
$ jq -Mnc '["a","c","a","b"][["a"]]'
[0,2]
```

See also jq [indices](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#indices(s)) builtin (which uses it in its [implementation](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L28))

This may be too tricky to recommend using in the general case compared to a more obvious approach and if `.letters` contains duplicates then the simplistic `length==1` check won't work.